# Allow only numbers with dot in html

Tags: html

How can i allow only numbers and dot in input area using patterns and using button

```
<input type="text" id="amt" name="amount" pattern="[0-9-.]" title="numbers with dot allowed">
<input type="button" value="submit">
```

Comment: Do you mean there has to be a dot or that it is the only non-numeric character allowed? Maybe you just want to be sure that you can use the value as a number?

Comment: yes dot is allowed and numbers only

Comment: @JoeMike Do I get it right - any numberic value with dot separator is allowed? It cannot just be only dot itself? So for example VALID values are "10.10", "1213.00" but NOT ".", "1.a", "fooo.bar"?

Comment: So for example VALID values are "10.10" thats wat i want

Comment: Here is a simple one which allows for exactly one decimal, but no more:

<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" />

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
pattern="[0-9.]"
```